# Unable to return a json inside Future[JsValue] from a WebSocket in Play 2.4

Tags: json, scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.4

I have implemented Play framework's `WebSocket` so as to perform server communication using a WebSocket instead of Http. I have created a function as `WebSocket.using[JsValue]`. My json response is stored inside a `Future[JsValue]` variable and I am trying to fetch and return the json value from within `Future[JsValue]` variable. However I have been unable to return the json data from the `Future[JsValue]` variable. When I tried creating the WebSocket function as `WebSocket.using[Future[JsValue]]`, in this case I was unable to create a json `FrameFormatter` for it.

```
def socketTest = WebSocket.using[JsValue] { request =>
val in = Iteratee.ignore[JsValue]
val out = Enumerator[JsValue](
      Json.toJson(futureJsonVariable)
    ).andThen(Enumerator.eof)
(in, out)
}
```

`futureJsonVariable` is a variable of type `Future[JsValue]` In the above code the error at runtime is `No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.` **How can I return a json using a WebSocket method in Scala ?** How can it be achieved using an Actor class instance ? If anyone knows best available online tutorials for WebSocket in Play framework. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tryAccept`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WebSocket$) to return *either* the result of the future when it is redeemed, or an error:

```
def socketTest = WebSocket.tryAccept[JsValue] { request =>
  futureJsonVariable.map { json =>
    val in = Iteratee.ignore[JsValue]
    val out = Enumerator(json).andThen(Enumerator.eof)
    Right((in, out))
  } recover {
    case err => Left(InternalServerError(err.getMessage))
  }
}
```

This is similar to `using` but returns a `Future[Either[Result, (Iteratee[A, _], Enumerator[A])]]`. The [`Either[Result, ...]`](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/02/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-7-the-either-type.html) allows you to handle the case where something unexpected occurs calculating the future value `A` by providing a [`play.api.mvc.Result`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Results) in the `Left` branch. The corollary is that you need to also wrap the "happy path" (where nothing goes wrong) in `Right`, in this case the iteratee/enumerator tuple you'd ordinarily return from `using`.

You can do something similar with the `tryAcceptWithActor` function.

Comment: many thanks for your help, it worked for me but can I ask you for a thing, if you can give me a little explanation about what the above code does, using the `Left` and `Right`, and have you done something like you have mapped the `in,out` into the `Future` variable and directly sent them to `Right` ?